# HTML Directory Viewable on Wordpress System

Tags: html, wordpress, .htaccess, multisite

I have a Multisite Wordpress system (multisite.com) where I'm running a site with an addon-domain/alias (domain.com).

I uploaded old files in HTML to multisite.com/domain

The HTML is displayed, but the image files or any other source file that is coded as src="/whatever" looks for the source on multisite.com/ instead of multisite.com/domain/

I'm thinking it's because it's in a Wordpress system or a Wordpress Multisite system... I'm not sure, but I assume the correction would be done in the htaccess file.

Can someone tell me get the source code to display the address of the actual location?

Comment: So your main site for the hosting account is a WP multisite and you have another site, not part of the multisite network, added to the hosting account as an add-on domain. Is this correct?

Comment: @Nikolay Yes, but they are both the same domain... domain.com is an addon domain ontop of multisite.com and I've uploaded the html folders to domain.com/oldfolder/ but those files are showing up on multisite.com/domain/oldfolder